# Select subitem in Listview and change value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, subitem

I have a listview in the "details" mode that looks something like:

```
#################
Name  #  Property
#################
#Itm1 # Subitm1
#Itm2 # Subitm2
#################
```

Very simple, but the problem I am running into is I cannot select "Subitm1" in the list at runtime. I can select and highlight every item in the first column, but clicking on any item in the second column does nothing (I would expect it to highlight the item like in the first column).

Specifically, I'm trying to add the ability for a user to be able to double-click a sub-item and change it's value directly at the listview. Is there a specific setting I'm missing here?

Comment: what platform is this, wpf, winform, else?

Comment: While you can do this with a ListView control, it is painful to set up. Have you thought about using a Grid control instead?

Comment: I have, but I personally found the grid view to be pretty distasteful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to select the whole row when subitem was clicked, try to use `FullRowSelect` property of `ListView`.
To handle double-click on a subitem, try this:

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    // Use hit.Item
    // Use hit.SubItem
}
```

If you want allow end-user to edit subitem's text at the listview, I'm afraid the easiest way is to use Grid control. Alternative way is to try something like this:

```
private readonly TextBox txt = new TextBox { BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Visible = false };

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listView1.Controls.Add(txt);
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
    txt.Leave += (o, e) => txt.Visible = false;
}

private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);

    Rectangle rowBounds = hit.SubItem.Bounds;
    Rectangle labelBounds = hit.Item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Label);
    int leftMargin = labelBounds.Left - 1;
    txt.Bounds = new Rectangle(rowBounds.Left + leftMargin, rowBounds.Top, rowBounds.Width - leftMargin - 1, rowBounds.Height);
    txt.Text = hit.SubItem.Text;
    txt.SelectAll();
    txt.Visible = true;
    txt.Focus();
}
```

Comment: hi, is there anyway to determine which column the item being edited belong?